# Stack element Relative postioning in flutter with no change in different orientations ( portrait / landscape )

Tags: flutter, stack, orientation, positioning

How to make the Stack elements not change while rotating from portrait to landscape?
I have added and image and my stack code, don't know what am i doing wrong can anybody help me please.

I have tried changing the designed based on the orientation but no luck i think there must be an easy way while searching i coming across this " Positioned.fromRect() " but don't know how to use it or what it does.

Thank you in advance.

[portrait Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MCYT.jpg)

[Landscape Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teImU.jpg)

**displayHeight(context) and displayWidth(context) gets the value from the above functions.**

```
double displayHeight(BuildContext context) {
  debugPrint('Height = ' +
      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - kToolbarHeight).toString());
  return displaySize(context).height - kToolbarHeight;
}

double displayWidth(BuildContext context) {
  debugPrint('Width = ' + MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString());
  return displaySize(context).width;
}


    Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
            children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'images/header.png',
                  height: displayHeight(context) * 0.38,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: displayHeight(context) * 0.02,
                width: displayWidth(context),
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "Want to promote good health? you are in a right place.",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    softWrap: true,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.05,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.6)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: displayHeight(context) * 0.04,
                child: Container(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'images/run2.png',
                    height: displayHeight(context) * 0.37,
                    width: displayWidth(context) * 0.95,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
    
              //top Sponsor button code parts
    
              Positioned(
                top: displayHeight(context) * 0.2,
                left: displayWidth(context) * 0.1,
                child: new RaisedButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  child: new Text(
                    'Sponsor A Run',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.06,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: isButtonPressed
                      ? Colors.orange
                      : Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.4),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
    
              Positioned(
                top: displayHeight(context) * 0.08,
                right: displayWidth(context) * 0.03,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'images/pot1.png',
                  height: displayHeight(context) * 0.3,
                  width: displayWidth(context) * 0.3,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Image Orientation problem Will be Solved Try to do this way :

In Your Pubspec.yml file add this package :

```
dependencies:
  flutter_exif_rotation: ^0.3.2
```

Then Do Like This :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_exif_rotation/flutter_exif_rotation.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// The stateful widget
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

/// The class with the scaffold
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null && image.path != null) {
      File rotatedImage =
          await FlutterExifRotation.rotateImage(path: image.path);

      if (image != null) {
        setState(() {
          _image = rotatedImage;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Future getImageAndSave() async {
    final image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null && image.path != null) {
      File rotatedImage =
          await FlutterExifRotation.rotateAndSaveImage(path: image.path);

      if (image != null) {
        setState(() {
          _image = rotatedImage;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Exif flutter rotation image example app'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: _image == null
              ? new Text('No image selected.')
              : new Image.file(_image),
        ),
        persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
          new FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: getImageAndSave,
            tooltip: 'Pick Image and save',
            child: new Icon(Icons.save),
          ),
          new FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: getImage,
            tooltip: 'Pick Image without saving',
            child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think its a dependencies for camera fix which is totally different thing what i'm looking for. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_exif_rotation